# Google Coral / Mendel Linux - packages cannot be authenticated

Tags: google-coral

I am trying to compile Mendel Linux on Ubuntu 20.04 as per:

https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md

I receive the following:

> WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
> libedgetpu1-std python3-tflite-runtime python3-pycoral
> E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
> make: *** [/rootdir/build/rootfs.mk:153: /rootdir/out/target/product/imx8m_phanbell/obj/ROOTFS/rootfs_arm64.patched.img] Error 100

I tried installing the three packages as per:

https://coral.ai/software/#debian-packages

I also tried :

```
$ sudo apt-key update  
$ sudo apt-get update  
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but I still get the above warning and error.

How can I authenticate the above packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem recent.
Finally, I solve it a few minutes ago.

The Key is to use root user to run the whole tutorial.

```
$sudo -i #change the user to root
```

I think the problem is about Docker user.

```
$sudo apt-get install docker.io
$sudo adduser $USER docker
```

Before the step "Build the tree" in the tutorial, I use standard user to run the command.
So $USER will be standard user

In the step Build the tree, I face some permission problem.
So I change to root to build the kernel.
The $USER should be root.

I think different $USER cause this problem.

Hope I can heard some good news.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to respond.

I was trying to compile as a normal user as opposed to root. I created a Linux guest on another computer and followed my previous steps (as a normal user). Everything compiled there as it should. I haven't figured out yet why I can't compile using my first setup but I will update if I find a solution.